# Delay till ajax response like thread.sleep()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have button which post values of form to url but during post i want to capture that value into my database too.
So on button click i made new thread of ajax and paused  by while loop so user can not redirect due to post of form.

**But problem is program not responding in while loop and not posting ajax call.**

```
function btnSubmitId_Onclick() {

    window.setTimeout(function () {

        var FirstName = $(txtFirstNameId).val()
        var Email = $(txtEmailId).val()

        AJAXPost(   //Url
                "Signup"
                , //Data
                {Ip: Ip, CustomerKey: CustomerKey, FirstName: FirstName, Email: Email }
                , //Success
                function (data) {
                    response2 = true;
                }
                , //error
                function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
            );

    }, 0);


    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while (response2 == false)

}

var response2 = false;
```

Comment: Well I'd do it differently: when success callback is done execute your function, your idea of waiting for end of ajax call seems a little troublesome for me. Do something like this: `success: function(data) { executeFunction(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **really shouldn't do that**. Active waiting is likely to block the **whole browser** or at least the current tab.

Put all code that needs to run after the request succeeded in the success callback.

Since you apparently want to both submit the form normally *and* use AJAX (why?!), the solution is rather simple: prevent the original submit from being handled by the browser by calling `e.preventDefault()` (`e` being the first argument passed to the jQuery event handler) and after the AJAX request succeeded `.submit()` the form. To avoid the AJAX request from being sent again you might need to unbind the submit event handler or set a variable after the AJAX request completed.